# Is there a way to sync rmd file and the compiled html file?

Tags: r, visual-studio-code

For regular markdown file, vscode can sync it with the compiled html so that one can scroll them synchronously. I couldn't find a way to achieve that for rmarkdown in vscode. Is there a way to do so?

I have checked the setting for R and markdown in vscode, but cannot find a way to achieve it.

Comment: Or is there any editor that can achieve this function? Sync scrolling rmd and its knitted html.